# How to use IN to compare multiple strings as exact match in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
print value in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1")
```

when `value="abc"` this return `TRUE`.
How do I make this comparison to return true only for `EXACT MATCH` not for `Sub Strings`?

My `in (....)` contains like 40 strings changing it `into =='..' or == '..' or  == '..'` is unrealistic.

How can I force `IN` to compare exact match strings?

**EDIT:**
Basicly I want to know why:

`print "abc" in ("abc d")`    is **TRUE**

`print "abc" in ("abc d","ab")`    is **FALSE**

I just don't understand this behavior.

Comment: Do you mean to match each token in each string? e.g. abc in the second string matches abc in the first, but not abcd? Have you got any code you have tried already?

Comment: You can use regex for the same, but depending on the needed text, using regex might be a overkill

Comment: @Phil I want `print "abc" in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1")` to return FALSE because "abc" is not listed as string in the in (,) in case `print "abc" in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1", "abc")` then it should be TRUE

Comment: `print "abc" in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1")` does print `False`

Comment: @schwobaseggl why print "abc" in ("abc ver1") returns True?

Comment: @avi The code you've presented already does what you've said, `print value in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1")` where `value` is `"abc"` *does* return `False`. `"abc" in ("abc ver1")` returns `True` because it's the same as `"abc" in "abc ver1"` which is clearly true

Comment: @NickA "clearly true" is because IN does something else than what I expect. I expect exact match of the WHOLE string not part of the string. If I search for "ABC" i want a match for "ABC" NOT "ABC VER1".

Comment: `in` between two strings treats strings as a list of characters, or list of substrings. That is why `'b' in 'abc'` is `True`. If you use `in` between a string and a list, it treats the string as a potential element of that list, and only exact matches will return true. Something that is a bit weird in python is that `('a')` doesn't lead to a tuple containing exactly `'a'`. Instead you would have to use `('a',)` to imply that you were planning to make a number of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is asking why:

```
"abc" in ("abc d")
```

returns `True` and:

```
"abc" in ("abc d","ab")
```

returns `False`.

Because the first expression is just wrapped in brackets it's akin to:

```
"abc" in "abc d"
```

Note that it doesn't act as a tuple because there's only 1 element.

Whereas

```
"abc" in ("abc d","ab")
```

Does use `("abc d","ab")` as a tuple (because of the comma meaning multiple elements), and so it searches for a matching element.

Comment: Ok I understand that.. so IN operator isn't helpful for me. What operator I should use for exact match between input and list of strings? say I have list of names "DAVID RO", "DAVID GIL" ,"JACK S" I want to return TRUE only if the variable is identical to one of the values in this list

Comment: Use `in`, but you have to ensure what you're searching is actually a list` `("david")` is not a list for example, but `("david", "jim")` is

Comment: @avi seeing as your issue seems to be with tuples my suggestion is to simply replace your round brackets with square ones, use `["abc d"]` for example instead of `("abc d") `

Comment: To make it short: `("abc d")` is not a tuple, `("abc d",)` is.

Answer (score 1):

Now you changed the question I will reply to this:

> **EDIT:** Basicly I want to know why:
>
> print "abc" in ("abc d") is **TRUE**
>
> print "abc" in ("abc d","ab") is **FALSE**
>
> I just don't understand this behavior.

In the first case you are checking if your string is inside another string `("abc d")` is equivalent to `"abc d"`

In the second case you are checking if your string is inside a list of strings, meaning that it has to **match exactly** one element in the list, very different from first case.

Comment: The noteworthy issue being: `(1)` is not a tuple, `(1,)` is.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
print [value==x for x in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1")]
```

**Result:**

```
[False,False]
```

if `value='abc'`

**Edit:** more direct answer:
You can't use `in` to compare exact match , it only test if a value "in" other value not equal exactly to it

you can test the length with it (in addation)

Comment: then `True in previous_result ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) like this:

`any(x == value for x in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1"))`

Demo with python 2.7

```
>>> value = 'abc'
>>> any(x == value for x in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1"))
False
>>> value = 'abc ver 1'
>>> any(x == value for x in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1"))
True
```

**EDIT**

Wait a minute!

```
>>> value = 'abc'
>>> print value in ("abc ver 1","abc ver 1.1")
False
```

Your question is wrong!

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `[]` for this to work (`x==value for x in (...)` is a valid generator expression)

Comment: But... `a in b` means is exactly the same as `any(a==x for x in b)`

Comment: Check next answer